# K8s cluster working with Openshift?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

I know that Openshift uses some K8s components to orchestrate PODS. Is there any way K8 and Openshift integrate together?. Means I should see the PODS which are deployed with K8s in Openshift UI and vise versa.

Followed Openshift as POD in K8 [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/openshift-origin/README.md),but I was struck at Step-4, unable to find kubernetes account key in GCE cluster (/srv/kubernetes/server.key).

Or is any way K8 nodes `join` under Openshift cluster?

Comment: You're deploying openshift on a GCE k8s cluster, correct?

Comment: Yes, deploying openshift POD on GCE k8 ckuster

Comment: What's the error? In your instructions, there is a script for fetching the .key file precisely for GCE, does it work for you?

Comment: No error yet, I have not run the command. Supposed to run `echo "sudo cat /srv/kubernetes/server.key; exit;" | gcloud compute ssh ${KUBE_GCE_INSTANCE_PREFIX}-master --zone ${ZONE} | grep -Ex "(^\-.*\-$|^\S+$)" > ${OPENSHIFT_CONFIG}/serviceaccounts.private.key`, but I found that there are no `/srv/kubernetes/server.key`